# Play 2 dependency on a local module in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am kind of new to PlayFramework 2 and can not figure out how to resolve play 2 application dependencies. I need to add dependency on a local module loaded in IntellijIdea, not a jar file or repository.

While adding module dependencies in Idea project setting works just fine and ide itself is able to resolve them (autocompletion, imports etc are working), when trying to run in play2, its compiler cannot resolve any dependencies.

I manually configured Build.scala (adding val appDependencies = Seq("" % "" % "")) but am puzzled as to what resolvers I should use. I cannot point to a jar file, as it is a work in progress and such a file should be updated too often. Doing so would defeat the whole purpose of managed dependencies.

Comment: so far it seems that the only option is to add dependencies on jar files - one way or another. This is very disappointing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play's main build mechanism uses SBT, which needs to know how to find all sources required for the build. There are several options for this:

- make your module an SBT project itself and publish it to your local ivy repository. However that might be somewhat complex at this stage, and would involve adding your local ivy repository to the resolvers and re-publishing every time you change something in the module
- declare your module as a [sub-project](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Multi-Project). Play's documentation describes the process of [working with sub-projects](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SBTSubProjects), I think this is the way you'd like to try out since then the `idea` command on Play's console will generate the IntelliJ configuration for the main application and the module.